# Python Change Calculator Variables Placement

Tags: python, if-statement, variables, calculator

I'm having trouble figuring out where to place variables related to each coin and how to properly declare them.
IE: Pennies = 1, Quarters = 25.

I need to make minimum changes to the existing code, but need to figure out how to make it work.

```
numPennies = int(input('Enter the number of pennies: '))
numNickels = int(input('Enter the number of nickels: '))
numDimes = int(input('Enter the number of dimes: '))
numQuarters = int(input('Enter the number of quarters: '))
totalCentValue = numPennies + numNickels + numDimes + numQuarters
totalDollars = totalCentValue / 100
if totalDollars < 100:
    print('Sorry, the amount you entered was more than one dollar.')

elif totalDollars > 100:
    print('Sorry, the amount you entered was less than one dollar.')

else:
    totalDollars == 100
    print('Congratulations!')
    print('The amount you entered was exactly one dollar!')
    print('You win the game!')
```

Comment: Maybe you should try putting some coefficients in your `totalCentValue` calculation.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“I don't know how to do my howework” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: Also see Stack Overflow guidance on [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).  Simply dumping your assignment here is unacceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following may help, just some advice of seeming inconsistencies in your code. Since it's obviously classwork (or at least educational), I'll provide guidance rather than straight solutions.

---

```py
totalCentValue = numPennies + numNickels + numDimes + numQuarters
```

That's actually the number of *coins* that you have rather than the value of those coins. For example, a nickel is worth five cents so should be factored into the calculation as `numNickels * 5`. Ditto for the other non-penny coins.

You can simply multiply by the constant value, or set up names to indicate those values (before the calculation). That would be something like:

```py
numQuarters = int(input('Enter the number of quarters: '))

valPenny = 1      # Insert here, before use.
valNickel = 5
:
totalCentValue = numPennies * valPenny + numNickels * valNickel + ...
```

---

```py
if totalDollars < 100:
    print('Sorry, the amount you entered was more than one dollar.')
```

One dollar is a hundred cents so you probably want to change either the variable being checked or the constant you're checking it against. In addition, `<` would mean it was *less* than a value, not more.

Both these points also applies to the code immediately after that as well:

```py
elif totalDollars > 100:
    print('Sorry, the amount you entered was less than one dollar.')
```

---

```py
else:
    totalDollars == 100
    print('Congratulations!')
    print('The amount you entered was exactly one dollar!')
    print('You win the game!')
```

Not sure why you feel the need to change `totalDollars` here but you're setting it to the wrong value anyway. The total dollar value is one rather than a hundred.

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry I'm quite a bit new to all of this and still teaching myself a lot. That helped out a lot and got it going! Just to clarify, it's not a homework assignment but it is out of a debugging challenge I couldn't figure out!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create them before you use them.  I think you're looking for something like:

```
Penny, Nickel, Dime, Quarter = 1, 5, 10, 25
...
totalCentValue = numPennies * Penny + numNickels * Nickel + numDimes * Dime + numQuarters * Quarter
```

By the way, you don't want to check `totalDollars < 100`.  You're looking for `totalCents`.  totalDollars will be 1.